# Angular 2 Creating basic angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, gulp

I Tried to create a simple basic angular 2 application but it is not working. I tells me in console "System" is missing. But i'll compile every javascript to one minified file. Is their something wrong? Somthing is miss?

You can download the code here: https://github.com/Condra963/Angular2Test

npm install and npm start is all you need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: You never load Systemjs in your app. Either bundle or import it before loading your minified file.

Comment: Shane, i think i do load my systemjs. Or is this not correct?

        watch: [
            app + "js/**/*.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/**/*.min.js",
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*.min.js",
            "./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
            "./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"
        ],

Comment: Your minified file does not include Systemjs and the configuration for Systemjs seems to be called first in your script. I use [SystemJS Builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systemjs-builder) to bundle my app using gulp. I am not an expert on gulp but watch seems to indicate it checks for changes made to the file instead of bundling it with your app.

Comment: start with [this simple seed project](https://github.com/maximusk/angular-seed), it contains as little dependencies as possible

Comment: The simple seed project is not a solution for me.

How do i check if my SystemJS is included in my minified JS? And why is it not included while i added the path to the build?